# How can I get the count of tickets in ticket project by user_id

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all user information from the `users` table, and how many tickets this user opens in the `tickets` table.

I already get all the data from the `users` table but can't get the count of tickets for every user by user id from the `tickets` table.

`User.php`

```
public function tickets(){
  return $this->hasMany(Tickets::class);
}
```

`Controller`

```
public function index(){
  $users = User::withCount(['tickets'])->paginate(30);
  return view('admin.reports.index', compact('users'));
}
```

`Blade.php`

```
<td>
  @if($user->department_id ==  null)
  No Department
  @else
  {{ $user->departments->name }}
  @endif
</td>
<td>
  {{ $user->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}
</td>
<td>
  {{ $user->tickets_count }}
</td>
```

Comment: try to replace `paginate()` for `get()`

Comment: Hmm... Everything looks correct. Are you getting a blank in the third `<td>` column? Or is it displaying a number? Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos I replaced it but still give me 0

Comment: @TimLewis yes it's give me number 0  but must give me 2 as the tickets table

Comment: 0 might be the count of the tickets for that particular user. Are you looping your users? Is your relationship defined correctly? Each `ticket` should have a `user_id`. Maybe include your schema for `users` and `tickets`, and a small sample of the database table content. Also don't switch `paginate()` for `get()`; if you want to paginate the results, you need to use `paginate()` lol

Comment: How can I get for example the count of comments for every post in a blog project I see it's the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution, it was in the user model

```
 public function tickets()
 {
 return $this->hasMany(Tickets::class, 'assigned_to');
 }
```

I add 'assigned_to'